# Error in rep(xi, length.out = nvar) : attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the the mean of a variable across multiple datasets in R.  However I keep running into this error and can't seem to get past it. Suggestions?

```
mymean <- function(directory, observation, id = 1:400){
    all_files <- list.files(directory, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
    dat <- data.frame
    for(i in id) {
        dat <-rbind(dat, read.csv(all_files[i]))
    }
    mean(dat[observation], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Could it be the missing brackets after `data.frame` in line 3?

Comment: "object of type closure" means that you supplied a function name where a variable name was expected; could be due to the missing parenthesis as suggested. More generally: it's better to read multiple CSVs into a list of dataframes using `lapply`, then use `do.call(rbind...)` - search this site for many examples of the syntax.

Comment: Thanks, yes it was the missing brackets.  Thank you.  I had been staring at code for 7 hours trying to complete my course work that I had overlooked it and just could not see it at the time.  
Thanks for the tip on lapply and do.call(rbind...) as well.  Just starting out in R so I find tips like this to be extremely helpful